# Is Socket.Available guaranteed to throw a SocketException on disconnect?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

The information below is given on the MSDN article on the `Socket.Available` property.

```
If the remote host shuts down or closes the connection, Available can throw a SocketException.
```

The keyword here being **can**.  My question is:

Is `Socket.Available` just as reliable as `Socket.Receive()` to throw a SocketException on disconnect, and more directly, under what circumstances will `Socket.Available` **not** throw a SocketException?

Comment: In my experience Socket.Receive() is not reliable enough that you should use it to determine whether a connection has closed. On Win XP I have seen issues with receiving larger quantities of data. Socket.Receive returned 0 but if I put a sleep for a few ms there would be data available.

Comment: You are correct, sorry, I actually meant when Socket.Receive() throws an exception.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Internally [`Available` is calling](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,8218f9a9992e9e85,references) the native method [`ioctlsocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the command `FIONREAD`, if that function returns `SOCKET_ERROR` then it raises a `SocketException`.

So to answer your question `Socket.Available` not throw a `SocketException` when a call to `ioctlsocket` could be made without error.

Comment: So then under what circumstances will `ioctlsocket` cause an error?  The MSDN article is fairly vague (surprise, surprise).